# How to get scanner to skip space in Java string

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read in a string from a text file, but it is stopping at the first whitespace.  I thought to try to "group" the string with surrounding '$' but that's not working.  The program reads in a line of a file with coordinates and a string. I need it to read all the text input left on this line, and store it into a string. please and thanks for any help :)

```
Log.d(null, "scanning inputStream");
    try {
        do {
            String latlngString;
            String memory;
            //skip 'latlng:'
            scanner.skip("lat/lng:");
            //scan coordinates
            latlngString = scanner.next();

            double latitude = 0;
            double longitude = 0;
            if (latlngString != null) {
                latlngString = latlngString.startsWith("(") ? latlngString.substring(1) : latlngString;
                latlngString = latlngString.endsWith(")") ? latlngString.substring(0, latlngString.length() - 1) : latlngString;

                String[] latlng = latlngString.split(",");
                latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlng[0]);
                longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlng[1]);
            }
            //scan memory

            for(int i = 0;i<10;scanner.hasNext()){
            }
            memory = scanner.next();

            //this should remove the dollar signs from memory, and then save it as one string
            if(memory != null){
                memory = memory.startsWith("$") ? memory.substring(1) : memory;
                memory = memory.endsWith("$") ? memory.substring(0, memory.length() - 1) : memory;
                Log.d(null, latlngString + " " + memory);
            }
            //output of memory, latitude and longitude
        } while (scanner.hasNextLine());
    }catch(NoSuchElementException n){
        Log.wtf(null, "nosuchelement");
    }
```

Comment: I'm only trying to read the second portion of the line. I'm pulling in the whole line, and then splitting it

Comment: Your code will stop at the first whitespace and not progress any further because of your infinite loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; scanner.hasNext()) { }`. Iterator variable `i` in never incremented, so it will just spin in that loop, consuming 100% CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The `Scanner` class provides a `nextLine()` method for reading in whole lines:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--